# Height of content container changes when i toggle through nav pages. I want it consistant

Tags: javascript, html, css

when you open [this page](http://techbuyhelp.com/desktop2/cat.html) you see a scrollable navbar to the left and to its right is the content. i have set the height of the content container to 70vh and content into it is also scrollable. 
its works fine when it loads. but when i click other menus like retirement planning and then click back on health insurance menu. the height of the content container changes to random height. i want it to be 70vh.
when page is loaded first time 
[image]

when you click on another menu

[image]
when you click back on the first menu, the height of the content container is automatically changed

[image]

jsfiddle link

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/16nsvq37/1/">http://jsfiddle.net/16nsvq37/1/</a>

<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/16nsvq37/1/embed/"></script>
```

Comment: Paste your code into a code block or a code snippet within StackOverflow as links can die over time. Refer to [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post a functional code snippet instead of images. We will be able to help better.

Comment: Remove everything between line 39 - 42 in your java/main.js file.

Comment: delete the setheight function and give it a height in css

Comment: @MajiD thanks bro, i didn't thought of javascript file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete the setheight function and give it a height in css. thx to @MajiD for answer